# How Bootstrap 4 buttons change the state in a mobile view without a reference to CSS class?

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

I've got a basic example of a few buttons populated in a basic modular popup. I was going to ask how they change the state from active to inactive as in my code I don't see any visible change.

I was adding custom JS to add "active" class on click action and remove on the second click but still at least one button (recently clicked) remained selected even without "active" class attached to it.

I've prepared the code example in Codepen.io  https://codepen.io/krzysztof-d/pen/rNLqdMv but I found out that those buttons over there behave even differently as they are not stay selected as they should by default, right?

Please let me know what I am missing

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary w-100">1</button>
```

Update:

So the default behaviour of the buttons is different depending if in Desktop or Mobile view. You can test on Codepen example - in mobile last clicked button remains "selected/dark" (with change colour and focus around it) when in desktop view it instantly change back to white colour after mouse go away.

Now I work on selecting multiple buttons by adding active state - but I don't know how to handle this mobile behaviour as at least one button looks like selected even without "active" class attached to it.

My questions is how to make such button to look normal again (as other not selected) programatically?

In another words it doesn't seem to be a problem to make a multiple selection but I want to allow to deselect some buttons if someone make a mistake and this is where the weird part became. Here is the another link to Codepen with the same example with some JS added to add/remove active class from buttons - check it out in mobile view https://codepen.io/krzysztof-d/pen/OJXBwYm, try to select a few numbers and then deselect one or two.

Update with screenshot on request - button six in mobile view seem like selected but actually it was just deselected and class .active has been removed from it.

[image]

Comment: Actually looking into the Codepen example I can see that only external outline remains recently selected button. In Safari there is nothing remaining.

In my local I can see buttons selected (as expected) but this could be difference of calling different version of Bootstrap and jQuery libraries.

Comment: By saying the button is selected, did you mean the button is surrounded with shadows, after you close the modal? That's just the focus effect.

Comment: OK, so what happens on my local machine is weird and unusual and what is on Codepen is normal. I was so confused that I took my local behaviour as quite normal.

Comment: It turned out that this "strange behaviour" is visible only in mobile view - buttons remain selected after click - not only the focus effect but the whole button change the colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First or all, you don't need to write your own JavaScript to toggle the `.active` class on the buttons. Bootstrap has the [button plugin](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/buttons/#button-plugin) you can use:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary w-100" 
        data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false">1</button>
```

That would automatically toggle `.active` class when selecting/unselecting the button.

**jsfiddle demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/mfqyp8j3/6/

Secondly, when you select a button, there are 2 things going on. Bootstrap addes `.active` (if you're using the button plugin) and `.focus` class:

[image]

- `.active`: gives you the same background on the button just like when you hover it
- `.focus`: adds shadows around the button

When you click somewhere else, only `.focus` class would be removed. That's why you should see the button is filled with the background color without the shadows, the same as you hover over it.

When you unselect a button but your mouse is still pointing at it, `.active` class is removed but the hover effect as well as `.focus` is still going on, making the button look like you haven't unselected it.

As soon as your mouse moves away, the hover effect is gone, and only `.focus` is left. That's why you should see the button only has shadows.

If you want to distinguish the select and unselect state of the button a little bit more, you can write CSS to disable hover effect if the button is `.focus` but not `.active`:

```css
.selector .btn.focus:not(.active):hover {
    color: inherit;
    background-color: inherit;
    border-color: inherit;
}
```

**jsfiddle demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/mfqyp8j3/17/

**Codepen demo:** https://codepen.io/davidliang2008/full/yLJRZYy

A gif to show it's working properly in mobile view:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for this great answer but still this doesn't solve the problem.

jsfiddle is not good tool to use with mobile view so I've modified my first codepen example and added the data-toggle and aria properties. Classes are added and removed as you described without help of custom JS code but in mobile view a button without a class .acitve looks exactly the same as others having this class .active added to it.

Comment: So effectively there is no other way to deselect the button like clicking on another one - if this one you don't want to be selected you have the same problem but now with another button, if it was one already .active - you would make him not .active but it would remain visible as one and would produce wrong results.

Comment: @KrzysztofDabrowski: Huh? I've tested my jsfiddles as well as your codepen examples in mobile view but couldn't see the problem you described. In fact, your HTML structure would be the same regradless which views / breakpoints you're in. Can you attach screenshots in your OP to show that?

Comment: Just added the screenshot. Other then this my point was that all those visual changes are happening with or without a presence of this .active and .focus classes so there must be away to refer to this internal nested JS object parameters and methods.

Comment: @KrzysztofDabrowski: That's my point too. I am not seeing the issue even with your Codepen or my JsFiddle examples. Is it a cache issue? Can you try hard refreshing your browser?

Comment: It Has got  nothing  to do with a cache. Either visit the codepen link on your mobile or open chrome dev tools and select this mobile view button switch - visible in top left corner of dev tools on my screenshot in dark blue

Comment: Probably you still viewing this in a desktop view so bootstrap is not applying this change

Comment: When you switch to that mobile view your normal arrow cursor will be replaced by grey circle to simulate a finger touch.

Comment: @KrzysztofDabrowski: I wish I can post screenshot in the comment. Yes I am viewing it in Chrome but switch it to the mobile view so my arrow cursor becomes a grey circle. I am still seeing .active class got added when you first click the button, as well as .focus class. But when you unclick it, .active class goes away but not .focus class. Maybe that's what Bootstrap mentioned as sticky hover: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/browsers-devices/#sticky-hoverfocus-on-ios? It looks like the only fix would be to manually remove .focus after adding .active class?

Comment: But my style works on mobile view. Here is its copy to Codepen: https://codepen.io/davidliang2008/full/yLJRZYy

Comment: I’ve just visited the link you quoted, clicked on 4,5,6 middle row grey, click on 5 again, no visual change, click on X to close modal, click on main button to open modal again, only 4 and 6 remain active

Comment: My point is that on second click on 5 it becomes inactive but there is no visual difference on mobile view

Comment: @KrzysztofDabrowski: please see my update. I've added a gif to show it's working properly.

Comment: Thanks for the gif. In my case 5 button remains dark on second click. I was testing on iPhone both Safari and Chrome and on Mac with Chrome and Opera with the same results. Thanks for the time you spent on it and for your feedback

Comment: Then it must have something to do with https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/browsers-devices/#sticky-hoverfocus-on-ios then.

Comment: Just out of curiosity does anything work for you if you remove data-toggle and aria properties?

Comment: I just tested it with https://codepen.io/krzysztof-d/pen/OJXBwYm, and the .active class toggling worked but the #5 button remained dark. I think it's just because your codepen didn't have my disable-hover styles.